# Computing Riemann Roch space for $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $X=\mathbb{P}^2$ and we take $V=V(F)$, where $F$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$, and I'd like to compute a basis for the space $H^0(X,V)$.

By definition, we have $f\in H^0(X,V)$ implies that $\operatorname{div}(f)\geq -V$. But what is this actually saying about the poles and zeros of $f$? I understand this well for curves, but is this equivalent to saying the $\operatorname{div}(f)\geq \Sigma P_i$ where $P_i$ are the points on $V$? If not, how does $\operatorname{div}(f)\geq -V$ constrain the zeros and poles of $f$, and how can I use this to find a basis?

Comment: First, do you mean $x^2-yx$? Second, most of the world would write this as $H^0(\Bbb P^2,\mathscr O(2))$ or perhaps $H^0(\Bbb P^2, H^{\otimes 2})$, where $H$ is the hyperplane bundle. Or maybe $H^0(\Bbb P^2,\mathscr O([V]))$. The global sections are all homogeneous quadratic polynomials. Who is using this nonstandard terminology/notation?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I mean $f=x^2-yx$ (I picked this polynomial at random -- I am really interested in the general principal). Second, you can see this usage in the popular books by Hartshorne and Silverman -- they will write $H^0(X,D)$ (or sometimes $\mathcal{L}(D)$) as shorthand for $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}(D))$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Third, you have to be careful since $H^0(\mathbb{P}^2,\mathcal{O}(2))$ is isomorphic to, but not literally, $H^0(\mathbb{P}^2,V)$ -- I'm looking for explicit functions, after all.

Comment: You picked a singular curve on purpose. You should start by understanding that the divisor of $f$ is a linear combination of divisors (curves),  not of points.

Comment: @TedShifrin This still doesn't answer my question. It's ok if you don't know the answer! I want to know how the poles and zeros are prescribed in this higher dimensional case.

Comment: @TedShifrin It doesn't really matter what $f$ is, so I've removed it to avoid confusion. It is just a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is, quite simply, this:
$$H^0(\Bbb P^2,\mathscr O(V)) \cong \{\phi/F: \phi \text{ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $\deg F$}\}.$$
Note that if $f=\phi/F$, this is a *well-defined* meromorphic function with divisor $(f)=(\phi)-(F)$.

Comment: So would the dimension of this space be the number of homogeneous polynomials of degree $F$?

Comment: Yes, precisely, which follows immediately from my original comment. But you said you wanted to see it explicitly, so it's good to write this down explicitly.